# Remove inline styles from markdown in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm pulling in JSON data and displaying it with Text in my SwiftUI App, but some of the text contains inline styles in the MD. Is there a way to remove this or even apply the styles?

Example:

```
if !ticket.isEmpty {
    Text(self.ticket.first?.notes.first?.prettyUpdatedString ?? "")
        .padding()
    Text(self.ticket.first?.notes.first?.mobileNoteText ?? "")
        .padding()
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
}
```

The prettyUpdatedString prints out "Last updated by < strong >Seth Duncan</ strong>"

Update:

In an attempt to apply this fix to the Ticket Short Detail, an exception is being thrown.

```
Exception   NSException *   "*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: Range or index out of bounds"   0x0000600003f06370
```

I'm not sure what's going on here. Any ideas?

Example of Data shortDetail is being pulled from

```
{
id: ID,
type: "Ticket",
lastUpdated: "2020-07-23T08:19:12Z",
shortSubject: null,
shortDetail: "broken screen - @ CEH Tina Desk",
displayClient: "STUDENT",
updateFlagType: 0,
prettyLastUpdated: "6 days ago",
latestNote: {
id: ID,
type: "TechNote",
mobileListText: "<b>S. Duncan: </b> Sent to AGI for repair.",
noteColor: "aqua",
noteClass: "bubble right"
}
},
```

ERROR CODE

[image]

Screen I'm attempting to access...short detail is below name

[image]

Comment: Do you want to keep or only remove said styles this, it's obviously possible to do both but applying takes a bit more work. Just asking to provide the best answer for you

Comment: I would prefer to remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to play with RegEx in my opinion, in this case I would create an function that clears the markdown

**UPDATE**

Based on what I understood from your comment you want to replace   with an white space not an empty string.

To archive that I just replace all occurrences of   with an space " "

```swift
.replacingOccurrences(of: "&nbsp;", with: " ")
```

Leaving you with this code

```swift
// original answer had an incorrect regex 
func clearMarkdown(on str: String) -> String {
    // we build markdown open and close regular expressions we ensure that they are valid
    guard let match = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<[^>]+>|\\n+") else { return str }
    
    // we get the range of the string to analize, in this case the whole string
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))
    
    // we match all opening markdown
    let matches = match.matches(in: str, range: range)
    
    // we start replacing with empty strings
    return matches.reversed().reduce(into: str) { current, result in
        let range = Range(result.range, in: current)!
        current.replaceSubrange(range, with: "")
    }.replacingOccurrences(of: "&nbsp;", with: " ")
}
```

This function will clear all markdown stylings from your strings, but it will not format the strings, nor give you any information about the markdown taking in count your example the usage would be something like this

```swift
var str = "Last updated by < strong >Seth Duncan</ strong>"
str = clearMarkdown(on: str) // prints "Last updated by Seth Duncan" without quotes
```

If you require the styling to be applied the will not work but I can write something that will

**UPDATE 2**

After looking your problem I found out that you received a couple of strings with characters not available in the UTF-8 charset.The character in this case is `’` which is available in ANSI while those that use UTF-8 normally use `'`. This being said you just need to change the charset by

```swift
// Replacing this line
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))
// With
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.lengthOfBytes(using: .windowsCP1254))
```

I'm not mistaken this is one of the most complete charsets and matches (or closely matches) the ANSI charset, you can also use `.ascii` that I tested and seems to work

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Brilliant. This seems to work for everything but &nbsp; - how would I modify the function to remove those as well?

Comment: What's the problem? do you want to replace the &nbsp; with an space?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be the best solution.

Comment: Pedro, I'm thankful for the help and I've been using the code across my app, but I've hit an area where an exception is thrown. I've updated the question. Any ideas?

Comment: I saw your update I’m just not sure is “Ticket Short Detail” the string that you’re running through the function? I know where the error lies and it’s in here `let range = Range(result.range, in: current)!` why I do t know, which string are you running through the function?

Comment: Yes, the ticketShortDetail is a shortened version of the ticket details and is part of a separate set of data. It works on "Open" and "Pending" tickets, but when I try and view tickets with a different status it throws the exception. None of those tickets appear to have any inline MD styles. Could the absence of styles break it? I'll add an example later today if I can get to it.

Comment: I tried with some strings without markdown "Open" and "Some Lengthy Status" both don't have markdown and the function ran fine returning the strings as they are. That concrete case is somehow breaking the function but until I receive it I can't help, I'll await for the test case on witch it fails

Comment: I updated with a screenshot and example of data, but I'm not sure what would be most helpful for you. It's hard to show much since there's information I can't share.

Comment: You have a couple of options, I don't know how experienced you are debugging, but you can try placing a couple of break points on the function one in here `let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))` and other in here `let range = Range(result.range, in: current)!` and run through until it crashes and read the values of `str`, `current` and`result`. We can arrange if you want a screen share so I can help you. I evaluated the string you gave me and it's not the troublemaker

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see if I can figure it out. If I can't I'll check back in. Thanks!

Comment: It is breaking on this string: "MacBook won’t turn on ( doesn’t say it’s dead ) and charger light doesn’t come on when it’s plugg..." at 'let matches = match.matches(in: str, range: range)'

Comment: Also, this string breaks it: "my macbook blacked out again out of no where and this also isn’t my computer, mine is 1221 and the..." at the same place.

Comment: Found out the culprit here, your strings contain a char not available in utf8 causing the crash. Change this line `let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))` to `let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.lengthOfBytes(using: .windowsCP1254))` I believe this matches the ANSI charset being one of the more complete charsets you can also use `.ascii` I didn't test with any other and I really recommend `.windowsCP1254`. The symbol in this case is `’` and in UTF-8 it's normally used `'` it's a small difference but sufficient to lead to a crash

Comment: Also updated the response with the same info that the previous comment